# Assembly check type in register

Tags: assembly, gcc, gnu

I want to create a function in assembly that prints the value no matter what is in the %rsi register (The register the value is in)

This is the code:

```
    .section __TEXT, __text
    .globl _print
_print:
    pushq %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp
    leaq pr_String(%rip), %rdi
    movb $0, %al
    call _printf
    xorl %eax, %eax
    popq %rbp
    retq
pr_String:
    .asciz "%s"
pr_Int:
    .asciz "%d"
str0:
    .asciz "Hello, World!"
str1:
    .asciz "\n"
    .globl _main
_main:
    pushq %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp
    leaq str0(%rip), %rax
    movq %rax, %rsi
    callq _print
    leaq str1(%rip), %rax
    movq %rax, %rsi #works
    #movq $3, %rsi should also work but it gives segmentation error
    callq _print
    xorl %eax, %eax
    popq %rbp
    retq
.subsections_via_symbols
```

I have two strings called pr_String and pr_Int that I wan't to switch between however I don't know how.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is no way to tell the difference between an integer and a pointer to a string.

Comment: why is that the case?

Comment: A pointer is just an address.  And an address is just a number.  How would you tell if the number is meant to be an address or just a number?

Comment: Is there any way I could avoid using a pointer?

Comment: Not really, but not using a pointer would not solve your problem.  Fundamentally, registers always hold numbers.  It is impossible to tell a priori if the number is meant to be a number or something else.

Comment: Well then how does c++ do it with its std::cout stuff?

Comment: This is done with Polymorphism.  The compiler internally calls a different function depending on what type datum you want to print.

Comment: C++ types are known at compile time.  That's why `(uintptr_t) ptr` prints differently, even though that the `uintptr_t` and the `char*` have the same object-representation (bit-pattern, i.e. register value).  As fuz said, it calls a different overload, `operator<<(uintptr_t)` instead of `operator<<(const char*)`.  (I don't think that's normally called polymorphism, though; it's statically typed and not using virtual functions.  i.e. run-time data isn't involved in figuring out what code to run.)

Comment: You have suggested avoiding a pointer.  What is it you're really trying to do?

Comment: fwiw, The registers are physical storage.   The processor just remembers the last value it was told to remember; it doesn't *remember* anything about data type.  It is the program that knows what's in the registers, how a register is being used, what data type is there, not the processor.  And the program knows because it was written by a compiler or assembly programmer who knows.  The compiler knows because it is translating source code with declarations, that were written by a programmer.  So, the programmer knows and that goes into the program, but otherwise is lost on the processor.

Comment: If you want to write a program that can tell the difference between two possible types of a single value/variable, you can create and use a tag to tell you.  One construct, [tagged unions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union), binds together the tag and the data value.  Polymorphism also can support introspecting a reference to obtain the actual type of the object being referred to.